# Referencing a opentype font, works locally, but not live

Tags: html, css, font-face, opentype

In my CSS I have

```
@font-face{font-family:"MyFont"; 
src:url("MyFont.otf")format("opentype");
```

on my server, I have in the same folder-

```
Index.html
mystyles.css
MyFont.otf
```

but it never pulls it through, is there something I should know about otfs ?

Comment: Do you have a live example? It seems there is a space missing before 'format'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your code, it seems to be missing a ';', but in any case, you can check this tutorial:
[How to use CSS @font-face](http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/)

Or you can check this very helpful site and it's kits and generator

[fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/)

Bye

Answer (score 0):

.otfs aren't a good file type to use. No good example of font-face I've seen uses them.

You should also provide .woff and .ttf file-types, .svg files are also seen in font-face stacks.

See if this tool is any help: [FontSquirrel font kit generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)